# Why sizeof varies in given example of ctypes struct packing?

Tags: python, c, struct, padding, ctypes

I would really appreciate if any explanation can be given to output of following piece of code. I am not getting why `sizeof(struct_2)` and `sizeof(my_struct_2)` are different, **provided** `sizeof(struct_1)` and `sizeof(c_int)` is **same**.

It seems `ctypes` packed `struct` within `struct` in some different way ?

```
from ctypes import *

class struct_1(Structure):
    pass
int8_t = c_int8
int16_t = c_int16
uint8_t = c_uint8
struct_1._fields_ = [
    ('tt1', int16_t),
    ('tt2', uint8_t),
    ('tt3', uint8_t),
]

class struct_2(Structure):
    pass
int8_t = c_int8
int16_t = c_int16
uint8_t = c_uint8
struct_2._fields_ = [
    ('t1', int8_t),
    ('t2', uint8_t),
    ('t3', uint8_t),
    ('t4', uint8_t),
    ('t5', int16_t),
    ('t6', struct_1),
    ('t7', struct_1 * 6),
]

class my_struct_2(Structure):
    #_pack_ = 1  # This will give answer as 34
    #_pack_ = 4  #36
    _fields_ = [
    ('t1', c_int8),
    ('t2', c_uint8),
    ('t3', c_uint8),
    ('t4', c_uint8),
    ('t5', c_int16),
    ('t6', c_int),
    ('t7', c_int * 6),
]

print "size of c_int            : ", sizeof(c_int)
print "size of struct_1         : ", sizeof(struct_1)
print "size of my struct_2      : ", sizeof(my_struct_2)
print "siz of origional struct_2: ", sizeof(struct_2)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
size of c_int            :  4
size of struct_1         :  4
size of my struct_2      :  36  
siz of origional struct_2:  34 ==> why not 36 ??
```

**EDIT:**
Rename t6->t7 (array of struct_1) and removed *pack*=2 from struct_2. But still I see different size for `struct_2` and `my_struct_2`

Comment: What language is this? If "C" it's using some extensions I'm unfamiliar with.

Comment: Looks like Python to me, not C.

Comment: I think it's because `struct_2` is packed, so there's no padding after `t5`. But `my_struct_2` isn't packed, so there's 2 bytes of padding between `t5` and `t6` to get it word-aligned.

Comment: BTW, why do you have two `t6` members in `struct_2` and `my_struct_2`? Shouldn't the second one be `t7`?

Comment: Added [python] (removing [memory-alignment] to make room) because the question is about the Python "ctypes" module.

Comment: I suspect that the answer is became the offset of field t5 changes directly due to the packing option used.

Comment: @Barmar my bad, it should be t7. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Removed the typo's; renamed t6->t7(array) and removed _packed_ also. But still question is same. :)

Answer (score 0):

The difference arises from the presence or absence of padding between or after elements in the structure layout, because when the sizes differ, the larger one accounts for more bytes than are required for all the individual structure members.  Members `t5` and `t6` alone are sufficient to demonstrate the difference, and there is no difference if `t5` (only) is omitted.

A little experimentation shows that by default (i.e. when the `_pack_` member is not specified), ctypes provides 2-byte alignment for structure type `struct_1`, but 4-byte alignment for type `c_int`.  Or it does on my system, anyway.  The ctypes documentation claims that by default it lays out structures the same way that the system's C compiler (by default) does, and that indeed seems to be the case.  Consider this C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>

int main() {
    struct s {
        int16_t x;
        int8_t  y;
        uint8_t z;
    };
    struct t1 {
        int16_t  x;
        struct s y;
    };
    struct t2 {
        int16_t x;
        int     y;
    };

    printf("The size of int is       %zu\n", sizeof(int));
    printf("The size of struct s  is %zu\n", sizeof(struct s));
    printf("The size of struct t1 is %zu\n", sizeof(struct t1));
    printf("The size of struct t2 is %zu\n", sizeof(struct t2));
    printf("\nThe offset of t1.y is    %zu\n", offsetof(struct t1, y));
    printf("The offset of t2.y is    %zu\n", offsetof(struct t2, y));
}
```

Its output for me (on CentOS 7 w/ GCC 4.8 on x86_64) is:

```
The size of int is       4
The size of struct s  is 4
The size of struct t1 is 6
The size of struct t2 is 8

The offset of t1.y is    2
The offset of t2.y is    4
```

Observe that the sizes of `int` and `struct s` are the same (4 bytes), but the compiler is aligning the `struct s` on a 2-byte boundary within `struct t1`, whereas it aligns the `int` on a 4-byte boundary within `struct t2`.  This matches perfectly with the behavior of ctypes on the same system.

As for *why* GCC chooses the alignment it does, I observe that if I add a member of type `int` to `struct s` then GCC switches to using 4-byte alignment for the struct, as well as arranging (by default) for the offset of the `int` within the structure to be a multiple of 4 bytes.  It is reasonable to conclude that GCC is laying out members within a struct and choosing the alignment of the struct overall so that all members of every aligned struct instance are themselves naturally aligned.  Do note, however, that this is just an example.  C implementations are largely at their own discretion with respect to choosing structure layout and alignment requirements.

Comment: ctypes provides 2-byte alignment for structure type struct_1
>> If I use __pack_=4 explicitly even then I see different size.

Comment: If we use alignment and packing in C code then it gives the size as expected

    struct t1 {
        int16_t  x;
        struct s y;
    } __attribute__ ((packed, aligned(4)));

The size of int is       4
The size of struct s  is 4
The size of struct t1 is 8
The size of struct t2 is 8

The offset of t1.y is    2
The offset of t2.y is    4

How do we get this same behavior with ctypes in python? _pack_ = 4 is not working.

Comment: @AmitSharma, you misunderstand the meaning of  `_pack_`.  It sets the *maximum* alignment.  You can get less padding or even none by setting it to a small number, but you cannot force more padding by setting it to a larger number.  You can, however, *manually* pad a structure by adding a member that you otherwise ignore.

Comment: @AmitSharma, as far as I can determine, ctypes has no built-in mechanism for specifying a *minimum* alignment (the effect of GCC's `__attribute__((aligned))`).